# Angular NoopAnimationsModule Type Error matches Element is not a function

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

I'm getting this error after importing NoopAnimationsModule for my Angular 6 app

```
ERROR TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.TransitionAnimationEngine.processLeaveNode (browser.js:2976)
```

Answer (score 18):

This happened to me a few hours ago, and was probably caused by some outdated modules.

Running `npm update --save` fixed it.

Comment: before npm update --save recommend firstly delete node_modules

Comment: This worked for me also. I had to use rimraf to delete the node module and then I npm update and that fixed it

Answer (score 9):

@angular/core and @angular/animations should be same version.
Especially look for "^" symbol in package name in `package.json`.

It should be

```
"@angular/core": "6.0.5",
"@angular/animations": "6.0.5",
```

and not like

```
"@angular/core": "6.0.5",
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.5",
```

Comment: Best solution. Updating npm, will update all packages and might cause more problems!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem after adding the `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Fixed by putting in the correct order the imports of `BrowserAnimationsModule` the app.module.ts:

  `imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    **BrowserAnimationsModule**,
    MatDialogModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while developing in *Angular 6.0*, but it works for me in *npm Version 6.0.3*. So, delete `node_module` in your project, install the latest version of npm latest, and try again.