# Angular 6 - TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function at TransitionAnimationEngine.processLeaveNode (browser.js:2985)

Tags: angular6

Note: This is not [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007544/angular-noopanimationsmodule-type-error). Have tried the resolution steps mentioned in that error as well.

I am getting the following error in my Angular 6 app

```
ERROR TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function
at TransitionAnimationEngine.processLeaveNode (browser.js:2985)
at TransitionAnimationEngine.flush (browser.js:3021)
at InjectableAnimationEngine.AnimationEngine.flush (browser.js:3858)
at eval (animations.js:365)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:4708)
at AnimationRendererFactory.end (animations.js:363)
at DebugRendererFactory2.end (core.js:15153)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11623)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ensure you use the same version of angular/animations comparing with core.

Comment: They're the same in my case

Comment: @KyleBurkett we are facing some issues with the latest version of angular animations so roll back to 6.0.5 

`npm install --save @angular/animations@6.0.5`

Answer (score 1):

@angular/core and @angular/animations should be same version.
Especially look for "^" symbol in package name in package.json.

It should be

`"@angular/core": "6.0.5",
"@angular/animations": "6.0.5",`

and not like

`"@angular/core": "6.0.5",
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.5",`

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/52348690/1881626